# How can i open form in class with C#?

Tags: forms

I want to write class codes to open form. How can I make changes the codes to work?

**My Class Codes:**

```
public void formac(Form frm, Form formName)
{
    formName frm = new formName();
    frm.Show();
}
```

**Button Click Codes:**

```
openFormClass MyClass = new openFormClass();
MyClass.formac(frm,Form1);
```

Comment: improvements in code

Answer (score 0):

Hello and welcome to StackOverflow!
Unfortunately your question is not very concise on what you want to achieve. Maybe have a look at [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

From what you've shown, I'm guessing that you're just want to show another instance of `Form1` on a button click. Then the following should be sufficient:

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
{
    var frm = new Form1();
    frm.Show();
}
```

Comment: i want to write code to open form in class (parameter will be "Form Name")

Answer (score 0):

i want to write code to open form in class (parameter will be "Form Name")